# Rebuild .jar library from source files

Tags: java, android, compilation, jar

Hey guys I have a simple question.

I downloaded and used the [jml](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/java-jml) library to make my own messenger. This all worked until I decided to make an Android version of it. It appeared that I had to change 2 lines in two class files and patch 1 file in the source. So I downloaded the source and did this.

Now I need to make a .jar file out of the source again so I can add it to my project as an "external jar".

Screen of the source folder: [image]

I hope I could make my question clear.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command line use:

```
java -jar cf <jar-name> <files>
```

More information [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html).

Comment: I got it to work, but I forgot to mention that all files in the source are .java files. How can I compile the whole source at once?

Comment: You can use `javac`. Alternatively, you can import the project into Eclipse if it makes things easier (as others mentioned). Use File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace

Comment: I tried javac * but all source files are in different folders and so it gives me a lot of errors.

And when I import them into Eclipse it only finds the "example" folder with projects in it so it doesn't take all .java files. If i don't check the examples folder for projects it doens't even let me import anything..

Answer (score 1):

Try this, on menu `Project` -> `Properties` -> `Android`, at right pane check `Is Library`.
Build and find your `jar` file in your project output.

Comment: How do I import it into Eclipse? I added a screen to my question.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, you can export is a *.jar file.

Comment: Yes I'm using Eclipse but I haven't imported the source folder. How do I import it? I added a screen to my question of the folder.